# Can I access SVN and ssh://someAddress by a web browser?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Can I access Subversion and `ssh://someAddress` by a web browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [SVNProtocolHandler](http://tortoisesvn.net/SVNProtocolHandler) you can visit svn:// urls in Internet Explorer. It even supports the svn+ssh:// protocol, but it requires a configured ssh client.

**Note:** SVNProtocolHandler is created by the primary developer of TortoiseSVN, but is not part of TortoiseSVN.

[@**Stefan**: Thanks for the update]

Answer (score 3):

No, the "svn" part of that access scheme implies that the protocol to be used is SVN's own, then wrapped in SSH to make it secure. Since SVN is not a protocol natively supported by most web browsers, you need a SVN-to-web "gateway", that is, the SVN host must also run a web server, that in turn must access the SVN repositories and make them available over HTTP.